# Angular JS overriding A links outside of ng-app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hyperlink, location

I'm building my first single page app. It's only within the content of the page like a widget. (basically pagination).

I have links in the header which isn't to do with the angular app, and the links are constructed like this:

```
<a href="#">Basket</a>
```

I don't really have control of the rendered HTML for the link above. As I've read adding `target="_self"` will make angular not use it's routing service.

I can confirm that I'm not using `$routeProvider` or any routing. As it sits on one page and uses one template file.

I am however using the following Angular services:

```
$scope, $log, $location, $filter, $http, $anchorScroll
```

Also I'm using `$locationProvider` with `html5Mode` set to `true` and `requireBase` set to `false`.

I'm using Angular version 1.2.28

Whenever I click on these types of links angular seems to take over and does nothing. If I take off the `href="#"` the click event seems to work and angular doesn't touch it.

Any help would be appreciated;

Comment: Where's the ng-app set? On the body?

Comment: If there is no routing involved what actually happens when those links are clicked... ie how does it affect angular? What are they used for also? In other words define *"angular takes over"*

Comment: ng-app is set within the content, not on the body tag... like so:


`<div ng-app="listItems" ng-controller="MainController" ng-cloak>
                    <div ng-include="'../../js/views/news-template.html'"></div>
                </div>`

When these types of links are click they just appear to flicker/refresh the ng-repeat array of items.

These links are used for navigation around the site, dropdowns, etc

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find out the bug, issue seems to only happen in Angular Versions 1.2.28 & 1.2.27.

I went to use a newer version and it all worked fine, however I needed to stay within releases of 1.2 due to IE8 compatibility so I reverted to version 1.2.26 until my users upgrade to newer versions of IE 9+.

I eventually resolved this problem by having to strip all my code to a basic blank canvas app. And the issue was still present. Hope this is useful to anyone else who comes across with this.